# Should I use $in for a performant query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following data structure in a collection:

```
{
_id : ObjectId("4ec6c015482c4c8302000001"),
uid : ObjectId("4ec6c015482c4c8302003233") //reference to user's Object ID
someValue : some json object,
}
```

Said collection will be sharded on uid.

Between these two situations, which would be more performant for reads?

Option A)

Store References to each data structure in the users object and perform this query:

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$in: ids}}
```

Option B)

Create an index on uid and query this way:

```
db.collection.find({uid : ObjectId("4ec6c015482c4c8302003233")})
```

each result set will include 0-20 of the data structures from the collection.

Summed up: Will it be faster to find() 20 specific ID's or all objects that match an indexed ID value (the result set is also 20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option (B) is better and straightforward :

i) You do not need to store references of _ids seperately.

ii) If an index exists on`uid`, your query would be fast,no optimization needed.

iii) Other operations like `sort`, `limit`,`findOne` will work in basic syntax . 
With option (A),you will have to always fetch whole data and do operations on it .

Answer (score 2):

create an index on uid and the answer is simply like this.

```
      uid    V.S.   _id  _id  _id 
      /|\            |    |    |
  doc doc doc       doc  doc  doc
```

the more _ids you push into query, the more checks against _id which means extra i/o. and time for fetching document is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Option A) and don't have an index, option B) will be more performant. Even tough if you would have all data completly in memory it is more efficient to use B) (as the application only has to compare one values, and not several).

Comment: _id has an automatically created index that you can't delete, unless the collection is capped.